# Sink basket drain no luck nut stuck

Tags: drain, kitchen-sink

Trying to install a garbage disposal and first step is removing the current flange. This one doesn't have the lock nut that so many videos show. Was able to remove all the hardware but now am unable to get the actual flange out. It looks like there is quite a bit of putty or something in there, perhaps gluing it in place.

Have tried a rubber mallet, heat gun, pressure from a car jack, and soaking in paint thinner. Any other ideas on how to get this out? Or maybe we are missing a step...?

[image]

Comment: Good picture: Note the screwdriver slot on the bottom of the threaded portion. Perhaps this is meant to be turned, likely CCW, to separate the two flanges?

Comment: Have tried turning that, as well as using a soft grip strap wrench but wasn't able to get it to turn. The screwdriver slot looks like this and is a bit big for a flathead https://images.app.goo.gl/rkCsvdK1c85Dg26A7

Comment: I'll keep trying though. Wondering if this is maybe sealed with silicone sealant. Have sprayed some wd-40 to see if I can get it to loosen up some. May also try isopropyl if that doesn't work.

Comment: If it feels like silicone, try getting hold of a specialist silicone dissolver/remover product. Generic stuff like WD-40 & IPA have little to no effect.

Comment: Have you tried turning that threaded portion in both directions? It might be reverse-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

They sell a special tool that fits into those slots from either above or below the sink to remove that basket strainer.

Comment: You need that tool, and a wrench on it. And someone  holding the nut below with a pipe wench because it has no flanges on it. You can tell it's two pieces from where the caulk squeezed out, where it should have been plumber's putty because now this is a pita. Consider giving up before all you do is loosen it and it just spins... and then the only option left is mutilating it with a grinder.